# Calculating interclass correlation but with different observer experience

Tags: agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation, coefficient-of-variation, differences, bland-altman-plot

I have tried finding an answer to the following question both here and using PubMed and google but without luck.

I have been asked to calculate the intraclass correlation coefficient from the scoring of soft tissue lesions conducted by two observers. 
The two observers rated lesions in soft tissue (from photos) on a continuous scale. The data set looks like this:

```
ID Observer1 Observer2
1  20        23
2  3         4
3  2         2
4  32        29
5  15        14
```

The dual scoring was conducted on about 100 photos from different study participants and higher numbers indicate more lesions.

This should be straight forward, however, the two observers have different level of experience. Observer 1 is highly experienced and Observer 2 is somewhat inexperienced. Now I am unsure how to proceed. 
Should I consider this as two different methods since the observers have different level of experience and therefore use Bland and Altman statistics or can I safely proceed calculating the intraclass correlation coefficient?

The aim of the study was to validate this new method of photo scoring of soft tissue lesions (there is no gold standard method). Each observer was blinded from the other observers ratings.